# how do you access anchor inside of tab

Tags: jquery

We have an unordered list and on a click event we need to access a particular anchor inside of a tab. There are 7-8 anchors inside of the tab.

```
var $tabs = $('#tabbed-content').tabs(); // first tab selected

$('.a-credit').click(function() { // bind click event to link
$tabs.tabs('select', 1); // switch to 2nd tab
return false;
});



  <div id="tabbed-content">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#deadlines">Payment Deadlines</a></li>
              <li><a href="#methods">Payment Methods</a></li>
              <li><a href="#installments">Pay In Installments</a></li>
            </ul>


<div id="methods">
  <p><a name="1"></a>Content 1</p>
   <p><a name="2"></a>Content 2</p>
   <p><a name="3"></a>Content 3</p>
  </div>
```

If you click on an unordered list link, it should activate tab #2 and scroll to the a name. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(a).click(function(){
    var anchor = $(this).attr("href");
})
```

you can use $(this) to refrence the currently clicked `<li>` inside your `$(a-credit)` click function. You can use something like `$(this).attr("href");` to get the current reference target.

edit (after updated question):  use this to scroll to your element, INSIDE of your click event

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Comment: The problem is we want the selected tab to open, and it then scrolls to the anchor text.

Comment: Thanks.  I just got this working with:  $('a.ui-link').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 1); // switch to third tab
  
  var anchor = $(this).attr("href");
  document.getElementById(anchor).scrollIntoView(true);
  
    return false;
});

Comment: @profuse: thanks! your code works a lot better than mine. i will use yours. :)